# JQuery ajax in javascript

Tags: jquery, ajax, deep-linking

example code site link click: http://www.smyrnart.com/deeplinking/index.html

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(event) { event.preventDefault();});
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({      
         url: 'index2.html',       
         success: function(data){          
         $('#yourDiv').html(data);       
         }    
        }); 
    }); 
}); 
    </script>


<a title="" href="javascript:;">Click 5 times. Alert reload</a>
<div id="yourDiv" style="margin-top:50px;"></div>
```

**AJAX index2.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('a').click(function() {
    alert('CLICK X 2')
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED!!!**

jQuery.js version 1.3.6;

```
// Evalulates a script in a global context
globalEval: function( data ) {
    if ( data && /\S/.test(data) ) {
        // Inspired by code by Andrea Giammarchi
        // http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2007/08/global-scope-evaluation-and-dom.html
        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement,
            script = document.createElement("script");

        script.type = "text/javascript";
        if ( jQuery.support.scriptEval )
            script.appendChild( document.createTextNode( data ) );
        else
            script.text = data;

        // Use insertBefore instead of appendChild  to circumvent an IE6 bug.
        // This arises when a base node is used (#2709).
        head.insertBefore( script, head.firstChild );
        head.removeChild( script );
        **$(head+"script:last").remove();** 
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You should enclose the `script` in index2.html in `<script>` tag so that jQuery will know that it is a script and it needs to parse before setting it into html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $.address.unbind('change').bind('change', function(e) {     alert('problem') }); 
</script>
```

Comment: My problem is when index2.html multiple repeat procedures.

Comment: Dude your question is not clear. You should make your problem clear.

Comment: sory, - Index2.html clicked.
 -. Ajax requests into.
 -. $ bind.address works in an incident.
 - Re-runs of the index2.html.
 - $ Bind.address repeats 2 times
 - This is going to increase.
 - Probably the header, we're always working.

Comment: uptade question. I am grateful to you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think his problem is repeating code. You can see the pop up increasing all the time. Stuff I need to reset the transition functions. eliminates such problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to ajax in page data from a link and dump it into a div. If you simply want to do this, you can just use the $.load function.

```
$('#ajaxLinks a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var $link = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#yourDiv').load($link);
});
```

or if you want to do it through the $.ajax function...

```
$('#ajaxLinks a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var $link = $(this).attr('href');
   $.ajax({
      url: $link,
      success: function(data){
         $('#yourDiv').html(data);
      }
   });
});
```

If you use the $.ajax() method, you can also chain the success and error methods like so...

```
$.ajax({url:'link.html'})
   .success(function() { /* DO SOMETHING ON SUCCESS */ })
   .error(function() { /* DO SOMETHING ON ERROR */ })
```

Added event function -> "**preventDefault()**" see above & in notes...

Comment: uptade question. I am grateful to you for your help.

Comment: Where you have <a title="" href="javascript:;">Click 5 times. Alert reload</a> Change the href="javascript:;"   to    href="index2.html". Also, add prevent default event in your click function so it prevents the link from changing the whole page...   `code $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();  `

Comment: Unfortunately, the problem could not be resolved. You can test at http://www.smyrnart.com/deeplinking/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Here... I've revised your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>STACKOVERFLOW - jQuery Click 5 then AJAX Load Something</title>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
</head>
<body>
<a href="index2.html">Click 5 times. Alert reload</a>

<div id="yourDiv" style="margin-top:50px;"></div>
<!-- JS SCRIPTS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    i = 0; // Initialize Click Counter "i"
    $('a').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent link from forwarding to page

        // Checks if link was clicked 5 times
        if(i == 5){
            $.ajax({      
             url: 'index2.html',       
             success: function(data){          
             $('#yourDiv').html(data);       
             }    
            });
        } else {
            i++; // ELSE: Increment Click Counter "i"
        }

    }); 
}); 
</script>
<!-- [end] JS SCRIPTS (Before Body Tag Closure)-->
</body>
</html>
```

I also pasted this in Pastebin so you could grab it:
http://pastebin.com/zhUHRKrd